# PyCharm: how to run tests in all open projects?

Tags: testing, pycharm

I would like to set a "configuration" in PyCharm, that runs tests (e.g., nosetests) in *several* open projects. How can I do this?

I'm using PyCharm 2.6.2 on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the `all in folder` option in the tests runner and specify the folder that is common to the several projects.

I've also [added a new feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-7928) so that it can work in all cases (like if there is no common folder for projects or the scan of the other files in the common folder is not desired).